# Using normal Java Project in AndroidStudio and JAVA 8

Tags: java, android, android-studio, java-8

I managed to execute a normal Java Class with a main method in it.
For this I have a normal JAVA Module added to my already existing Android Project. 
The build.gradle for my module looks like this :

```
apply plugin: 'java'

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
}

sourceCompatibility = "1.8"
targetCompatibility = "1.8"
```

In this Java Module I will have some processes to maintain the app. So this is not code used by the app itself.

Now I would like to use JAVA 8 compatible code in my module, so I can use lamba expressions.

I get the Error message :`Call requires API level 24 (current min is 1)`, when trying to use of a foreach in my Stream.

Any help how I can configure the java module independently from the Android App, so I can use lambda expressions in my java code ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> so I can use lambda expressions in my java code

Any `minSdkVersion` supports lambdas

> To start using supported Java 8 language features, update the Android
>   plugin to 2.4.0-alpha4 (or higher) and add the following to your
>   module’s build.gradle file:
>
> ```
> android {
>   ...
>   compileOptions {
>     sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
>     targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
>   }
> }
> ```

`java.util.stream` requires     API level 24 or higher

https://developer.android.com/studio/preview/features/java8-support.html

Comment: Thanks for helping. I get an error "Error:Jack is required to support java 8 language features. Either enable Jack or remove sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8.". When enabling jackOptions, I get multiple errors when building. Any help ?

Comment: You aren't using `2.4.0-alpha4 (or higher)`

Comment: Read that link... ***Jack is no longer required, and you should first disable Jack***

Comment: Oh, though you'll have to download Android Studio 2.4 Preview... So maybe that is the problem

Comment: In my default Setting-> Appearance and Behaviour -> System Settings -> Android SDK : I have 25 (Nougat). Is that what you meant with 2.4.0 or higher, or I am wrong ?

Comment: That is the SDK, not the Android Gradle plugin version that is listed in the root level `build.gradle`

Comment: Do you mean "classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3'" in the project (gradle) or do you mean     compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2" in the app (gradle) ?

Comment: "Gradle plugin"... keyword "Gradle". `tools.build:gradle`... Update `:2.2.3` to be `2.4.0-alpha4 (or higher)`

Comment: Ok. Thanks. Understand. In the end an update of AndroidStudio worked for me. Thanks.